# Is there a way to use an external program to authenticate XAuth with StrongSwan IPSec?

Tags: ipsec, strongswan, xauth

I'm currently using StrongSwan for my iOS devices to connect. I was wondering if there is a way to use an external program for XAUTH? I currently have the following configuration:

```
: RSA server.pem
test : XAUTH "thisisatestpassword"
```

What I want to do, is let an external program decide if the credentials are ok. Is that possible? and if so, does somebody know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could maybe try the [xauth-pam plugin](http://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/XAuthPAM), which delegates the authentication to [PAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_PAM), combined with pam_script (see [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5284739/1158499) for an example).

Another option is to write a custom plugin for strongSwan that e.g. calls an external program to authenticate the users. There already exist several XAuth plugins that you could have a look at for ideas.

XAuth credentials that can be used by the *xauth-generic* plugin can also be provided from databases (using the [sql plugin](http://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/SQL)), or from custom plugins.